# Node Angular authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I want to use frontend routing with angular js (with $routeProvider), and login using passport js. I found out that there are many problems while redirecting, communication between frontend and backend, showing messages and etc. Does there exist any complete tutorial on this?

Comment: I don't know about any tutorials, but I've written a fairly extensive web application social network using Node, Angular, MySQL, Passport and others. Is there a specific question you have or are you just looking to get started?

Comment: Yea PassportJS is pretty good with authentication, check out the scotchio tutorial its pretty straight forward

Comment: yes, but it uses backend routing and backend redirections when user is logged in and etc... i wanted to do these with angular :-)

Answer (score -1):

I learned it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jh0er2pRcq8) but it's long. Maybe it helps. They use what you need.

Comment: It actually is! If you go side by side developing while watching you can really learn a lot